# How to query neo4j lucene index with field grouping via REST?

Tags: lucene, neo4j

We have data in our graph that is indexed by Lucene and need to query it with a
[Field Grouping](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/queryparsersyntax.html)

The example in the link above shows the Lucene syntax to be:

```
title:(+return +"pink panther")
```

I can't figure out how to send a request like that via http to the REST interface. Specifically, the space in the second term is causing me problems.

Our data is actually a list and I need to match on multiple items:

```
regions:(+asia +"north america")
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Update: For the record, the following url encoded string works for this particular query:

```
regions%3A%28%2Basia+%2B%22north+america%22%29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it enough to just URL encode the query using java.net.URLEncoder or something?

Comment: Yes, in fact it is. Turns out the http client I was using was causing problems. Switched to Apache Commons HttpClient and it works fine.